# Studio issue: when my app crashes stack trace shows up and the screen is cleared

Tags: android-studio, logcat

I have an issue which is really painful but doesn't happen all the time:

when my app is crashing I get the stack trace as expected but a couple of seconds later the logcat window is cleared and a system message (not always the same) appears like:

```
09-19 09:02:04.123 17817-17817/com.narb.test E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
09-19 09:02:04.125 17817-17817/com.narb.test E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
```

Why is studio doing that and how to change this behavior?